# How to load layout in code from xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com) and I have a problem with using XML layout in code. Usually I'm using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.
Of course I can create layout in code but I prefer to use XML files.

```
public final class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "FragmentOne";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.setText("some text");
        text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(text);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreateView()` you can use the `LayoutInflater` passed in as the first argument to inflate the layout.

Your code would look something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick replay, Im new in this library so I've many problems and doubts. It works thank you once again :)